# Image not displayed on python

Tags: python, tkinter

i am a beginner of python programming.i will place the images on the frame. but image not not diaplayed error shown below.
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/Users/kobinath/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/jj.py", line 5, in <module>
    img = PhotoImage(file="pic.jpg")
  File "C:\Users\kobinath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\kobinath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "pic.jpg"
```

what i tried so far i attached below.

```
from tkinter import *      
root = Tk()      
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 600)
canvas.pack()      
img = PhotoImage(file="pic.jpg")
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)      
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is the image properly formatted? Like did you convert it to jpg properly?

Comment: yes sir. .......................

Comment: I think the problem might be that only `gif` files are supported by `PhotoImage` ( i think I read it somewhere) so either try converting this to gif or using `PIL` module

Comment: sir  can you write code for me how to add the image on frame please

Comment: Please search this site. There are _many_ questions about showing jpg images in tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think its not possible to use `jpg` with `PhotoImage` directly, instead you might want to use `PIL` and heres how,

```
pip install PIL
```

After this, just say

```
from tkinter import *  
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
    
root = Tk()      
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 600)
canvas.pack()   
   
img_file = Image.open("sad songs.jpg")
img_file = img_file.resize((150,150)) #(width,height)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_file)
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)
      
root.mainloop()
```

[Here is a site to convert jpg to gif](https://ezgif.com/jpg-to-gif)

Do let me know, if any errors or doubts

Cheers

Comment: sir how to make clickable image

Comment: Do ask a new Q and link it here, ill help :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644137/how-to-make-clickable-image-in-python

Answer (score 0):

It may be a result of a new bug thats been going on with tkinter images where we have to keep a reference of the image to make sure it will work I hope this will fix it.

```
canvas.img = img
```

Also as @Cool Cloud has also pointed out it can also be the problem where it does not work with jpg files sometimes but for me sometimes it does too, so if its not working with you, you can just convert it into a png or gif(I would prefer png based on what has worked with me when I ran into these problems).
Also instead of the conversion you can try the PIL library it can be installed using

```
pip install PIL
```

And then you can use a class called PhotoImage(yup it has the same name as the tkinter class) to do the image loading and stuff, which is under the module ImageTk which can be used to deal with tkinter images.

Also you can pass the image object into this class as a parameter, you can create an Image object like so-:

```
img_obj = Image.open('annoying_image.jpg') # uses the Image module from PIL use import PIL.Image
```

Like so

```
img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_obj) # uses the Image module from PIL use import PIL.ImageTk
```

Also If you want to know more about PIL, its just basically a Image Processing Library of python often called as pillow also.

IMPORT STATEMENTS(JUST IN CASE ITS NOT CLEAR)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Comment: It's not a new bug. It's the way tkinter has worked for many years. The problem is simply that tkinter doesn't directly support jpg.

Comment: @CoolCloud: in recent versions of tkinter, yes.