# How to make Clickable Image in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner in python image programming. If I click the image I need to display you are clicked image 1.
like that. what I tried so far I attached below. It is not working answer displayed img 1 , img 1, img 1 always

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

def click() :
    canvas.img = img
    canvas.img1 = img1
    canvas.img2 = img2

    if(canvas.img):
        print("img 1")
    elif(canvas.img1):
        print("2")
    else :
        print("3")

img_file = Image.open("1.jpg")
img_file = img_file.resize((150, 150) )
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_file )
canvas.create_image(10, 50, anchor=NW, image=img)


img_file1 = Image.open("2.jpg")
img_file1 = img_file1.resize((150, 150))
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_file1)
canvas.create_image(200, 50, anchor=NW, image=img1)

img_file2 = Image.open("3.jpg")
img_file2 = img_file2.resize((150, 150))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_file2)
canvas.create_image(400, 50, anchor=NW, image=img2)

Button(root, text="Add",command = click,height=3, width= 13).place(x=190, y=260)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example

Here you can click the button and it gives you an effect of clicking the image.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

def main(event):
    if event.widget.cget('image') == 'pyimage1':
        messagebox.showinfo('First','You clicked the first image')
    elif event.widget.cget('image') == 'pyimage2':
        messagebox.showinfo('Second','You clicked the second image')
    elif event.widget.cget('image') == 'pyimage3':
        messagebox.showinfo('Third','You clicked the third image')

img_file = Image.open("sad songs.jpg")
img_file = img_file.resize((150, 150))
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_file)
b1 = Button(canvas, image=img)
b1.pack()
b1.bind('<Button-1>', main)


img_file1 = Image.open("feeling wallpapers.jpg")
img_file1 = img_file1.resize((150, 150))
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_file1)
b2 = Button(canvas, image=img1)
b2.pack()
b2.bind('<Button-1>', main)

img_file2 = Image.open("sad songs.jpg")
img_file2 = img_file2.resize((150, 150))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_file2)
b3 = Button(canvas, image=img2)
b3.pack()
b3.bind('<Button-1>', main)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope it helped you

Cheers

Comment: sir i have 3 images above i shown. if the user clicked first one image 1 clicked and 2nd image 2 like that working on

Comment: Ive updated the answer, its just what came to my mind, you can play around with it