# Is there a way to place a tkinter button behind tkinter canvas text?

Tags: python, tkinter

In other words, is it possible to create a button with Tkinter and place Tkinter canvas text on top of it? The normal workaround would be to simply create a label containing the text on top of the button. However, the button where I want to place the text is an image containing a color gradient and you need to specify a background color for the label.

In other words, how can I create an image that I can click on and execute a function (like a button would do) and place text on top of this button without the need of specifying a background color for the text?

Comment: Yes, there's a way, and there's also a lot of information already out there on how to do this. Have you tried to solve this yourself, and have you searched Stack Overflow? For example, I searched `[tkinter] canvas click image`, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63644137/16775594) is one of the first results. Please show your research effort and attempts to solve the problem in your question. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: You can have both text and image in a button but you need to set `compound='center'` option.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to place a tkinter button behind tkinter canvas text?

No, there is not. Windows will always be on top of other canvas objects.

From the official documentation:

*"Window items are an exception to the above rules. The underlying window systems require them always to be drawn on top of other items. In addition, the stacking order of window items is not affected by any of the canvas widget commands; you must use the Tk raise command and lower command instead."*

> In other words, how can I create an image that I can click on and execute a function (like a button would do) and place text on top of this button without the need of specifying a background color for the text?

You can create your own button widget by placing the image on a canvas, then writing text on top of the image. You can then add your own bindings that fire when you click on the canvas.